# node.js & partial.js framework: How to use regex in routes

Tags: node.js, routes

My route specifies:

```
exports.install = function (framework) {
    framework.route('/', view_homepage);
    framework.route('/CreateRoom', redirect_createroom);
    framework.route('/Room', redirect_homepage);
    framework.route('/Room/(roomId)[0-9]{5}', view_room);
};
```

Specifically this:

```
framework.route('/Room/(roomId)[0-9]{5}', view_room);
```

This is made up and I am sure not the correct syntax. I looked at the documentation but did not find a solution or it wasn't obvious to me.

But what I am trying to do is get the 5-digit value after 'Room/' into a variable called `roomId` and then passed to the controller `view_room`.

Any help implementing this would be great.

Thanks

E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you can do is `framework.route('/Room/{roomId}', view_room);`

The function could look like this:

```
function view_room (roomId){
    if(!success) { //input check
        //response with 404 - resource not found 
    } else {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It worked! :)  I can't up-vote yet or else I would have up-voted your answer. I don't have 15 reputation yet.